DELETE Multiple Duplicate Rows Without Column ID
I have a table that contains 15 duplicate rows (for a total of 30 including originals + duplicates).  I have been tasked with writing a script to grab the duplicate records and delete them.  My problem is, the table does not contain an ID column like "shipment_item_id".  So I found a solution to use rowid to add my own id column and then I can distinguish the dupes from the originals.
I wrote a SELECT statement that gets the duplicates, but when I try to include it in a DELETE statement, I get an error :

ORA-00913 - too many values.

I find it hard to believe that 15 records is too many.
Here is the script.  I'm sure it's an easy fix but I have not been able to figure it out:
DELETE shipment_item
 WHERE rowid NOT IN (
                     SELECT MAX(rowid),
                            po_number,
                            item_number
                       FROM shipment_item
                      GROUP BY po_number, item_number
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                    )


Your subquery is expected to return one column only. max(rowid) I suppose.

The "two many values" does not talk about the rows, but about the columns:
you do a:
where <1 column> not in (select <3 columns>)

Do keep only the max(rowid) in your select and you're good to go.
That said...
You shall remove your having count(*) > 1 to avoid deleting non duplicated entries.
Let's say your table has:



rowid
po_number
item_number




1
A
B


2
C
D


3
C
D



Your subselect will return 3 for C,D (as intended),
but the having count(*) > 1 will filter out 1 for A,B because as you have only one A,B ,its count(*) = 1.
Thus the subselect returns only 3 as an entry to preserve, and thus... pooof with A,B!
And so...
You'll end up with:
DELETE 
FROM SHIPMENT_ITEM
WHERE rowid not in (
SELECT max(rowid)
FROM shipment_item
GROUP BY
    po_number,
    item_number
)


As others have pointed out you have 3 columns in your subquery which should be one.
I would like to suggest an alternative query with EXISTS instead of NOT IN. Depending on table size this could lead to faster execution (YMMV, hard to judge without knowing specifics).
DELETE FROM shipment_item si
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM shipment_item
  WHERE po_number = si.po_number
  AND   item_number = si.item_number
  AND   rowid < si.rowid
);


Yes, the EXISTS is an option to test. In my mileage though, Oracle had a disturbingly slow implementation of EXISTS. So when perf becomes an issue, knowing and being able to test some equivalent requests is a plus.

Also (not specific to EXISTS), be careful about the semantic inversion: here @Martin Schapendonk your rowid < si.rowid will keep the lowest rowid, while @CaptainGenesisX preserved the highest one. Sometimes it doesn't matter, but sometimes your use case makes it mandatory to choose right (for ex., if in addition to po_num and item_num the table had a "last_seen" field, of course the highest rowid had to be preserved!). You will always have to be extra careful (and test, test, test with SELECT before DELETEing) when translating a user need to a query.

Correct, this query retains the lowest rowid. This is based on the assumption that you want to delete future duplicates of your row and retain the original but as Guillaume pointed out you may make another choice if necessary.

It is not about number of rows, but number of columns (values you select).
DELETE 
FROM SHIPMENT_ITEM
WHERE rowid not in (      --> you are comparing ROWID with ...
    SELECT max(rowid),    --> ... max(rowid), but also ...
    po_number,            --> ... po_number and ...
    item_number           --> ... item_number
    FROM shipment_item
    GROUP BY
        po_number,
        item_number
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )

Remove superfluous columns from the subquery!
DELETE 
FROM SHIPMENT_ITEM
WHERE rowid not in (
    SELECT max(rowid)
    FROM shipment_item
    GROUP BY
        po_number,
        item_number
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )

